# Coin simulation program

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, nested-loops, ranged-loops

What’s the minimum number of times you have to flip a coin before you can have three consecutive flips that result in the same outcome (either all three are heads or all three are tails)? What’s the maximum number of flips that might be needed? How many flips are needed on average? In this exercise we will explore these questions by creating a program that simulates several series of coin flips.

Create a program that uses Python’s random number generator to simulate flipping a coin several times. The simulated coin should be fair, meaning that the probability of heads is equal to the probability of tails. Your program should flip simulated coins until either 3 consecutive heads of 3 consecutive tails occur. Display an H each time the outcome is heads, and a T each time the outcome is tails, with all of the outcomes shown on the same line. Then display the number of flips needed to reach 3 consecutive flips with the same outcome. When your program is run it should perform the simulation 10 times and report the average number of flips needed.

```
import random
choice_list = ["H", "T"]
curr = ""
count = 0
count1 = 0

while count1 < 10:
    flip = random.choice(choice_list)
    if len(curr) >= 3:
        while curr[-3] == curr[-2] == curr[-1]:
            print(f"({count} flips)")
            count1 = count1 + 1
            count = 0
            curr = ""
            break
    curr = curr + flip
    count = count + 1
    print(flip, end=" ")
avg = len(curr)/count
print(avg)

Sample output is shown below:
H T T T (4 flips)
H H T T H T H T T H H T H T T H T T T (19 flips)
T T T (3 flips)
T H H H (4 flips)
H H H (3 flips)
T H T T H T H H T T H H T H T H H H (18 flips)
H T T H H H (6 flips)
T H T T T (5 flips)
T T H T T H T H T H H H (12 flips)
T H T T T (5 flips)
On average, 7.9 flips were needed.
```

Comment: What is the error you are encountering? Are you having trouble with a specific part of your code?

Comment: i am getting one extra flip value at the end of the output

Comment: Your `break` only ends the current loop, not the outer while loop, so the code below the if statement runs one last time. You could move that code to happen before the `if` statement. Additionally, your inner `while` loop should just be a `if` statment, and so no `break` is necessary.